# haskell stack exception missing dependencies

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I want to add the `bound` library to my package dependencies;
The project is completely fresh initialized with `stack new`.
The entry in the `cabal` file looks like this:

```
executable DependendLambda-exe
  hs-source-dirs:      app
  main-is:             Main.hs
  ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:       base
                     , DependendLambda
                     , bound
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

I get the following error message:

```
While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for DependendLambda-0.1.0.0:
bound must match -any, but the stack configuration has no specified
version (latest applicable is 1.0.7)

Recommended action: 
try adding the following to your extra-deps in /home/MyProject/stack.yaml:
- bound-1.0.7

You may also want to try the 'stack solver' command
Plan construction failed.
Warning: build failed, but optimistically launching GHCi anyway
The following GHC options are incompatible with GHCi and have not been passed to it: -threaded
Using main module: 1. Package `DependendLambda' component exe:DependendLambda-exe with main-is file: /home/MyProject/app/Main.hs
Configuring GHCi with the following packages: DependendLambda
GHCi, version 8.0.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package bound
    (use -v for more information)
```

When I add the dependency to `extra-deps` it is still failing:

```
While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for bound-1.0.7:
    binary-0.8.3.0 must match >=0.5 && <0.8 (latest applicable is 0.7.6.1)
    comonad-5 must match >=3 && <5 (latest applicable is 4.3)
    transformers-0.5.2.0 must match >=0.2 && <0.5 (latest applicable is 0.4.3.0)
needed due to DependendLambda-0.1.0.0 -> bound-1.0.7

Plan construction failed.
Warning: build failed, but optimistically launching GHCi anyway
The following GHC options are incompatible with GHCi and have not been passed to it: -threaded
Using main module: 1. Package `DependendLambda' component  
exe:DependendLambda-exe with main-is file: /home/MyProject/app/Main.hs
Configuring GHCi with the following packages: DependendLambda
GHCi, version 8.0.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package bound-1.0.7
    (use -v for more information)
```

The `stack solver` command didn't help either ... what am I missing?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: The problem is that `bound-1.0.7` requires an older version of binary than is in the snapshot you are trying to use. I guess either use an earlier snapshot or specify `binary-0.7.6.1` and so on in your extra-deps as well.

Comment: To use the current development version of bound which appears to be largely compatible with GHC-8.0, you can add edit the `packages` field of your `stack.yaml` similarly to [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/sjakobi/9e54af86655c58acd0e5e3772320e321).